# How to get Paul Black's random file selector batch script not to select itself

Tags: windows, batch

I've been using Paul Black's random file selector batch script for a while to handle one aspect of playout on our radio station - and most of the time it works perfectly.

Except on occasion it adds itself, since, of course, it has to be in the same folder. At that point playback stops since .bat is not an audio file.

Here's the original script which I modified to push a file to our playout via CMD:

```
@echo off
:: ##############################################################################
:: # Title:      Select a random filename in the current directory [ folder ].  #
:: # Created By: Paul Black at TenForums.com/members/paul-black.html            #
:: # Created:    October 2020.                                                  #
:: ##############################################################################
title Select A Random Filename.
mode con: cols=80 lines=5 & color 17
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set n=0
for %%f in (*.*) do (
  set /A n+=1
  set "file[!n!]=%%f"
)
set /A "RAND=(n*%Random%)/32768+1" & set /A "rand=(n*%Random%)/32768+1"
echo. & echo "!file[%RAND%]!"
echo. & echo ^>Press ANY key to EXIT . . . & pause >nul & exit
```

So how would I get this to ignore itself, and not choose `random.bat`?

Comment: FYI, this script is pretty easy to break. It'll fail for filenames containing a variety of special characters, most notably anything with exclamation mark "!". Unfortunately it's not trivial to fix, either; Batch kinda stinks like that.

Answer (score 5):

[@Giacomo1968 answer](https://superuser.com/a/1823078/167207) has the right idea; change the `(*.*)` in your `FOR` statement to exclude non-audio files (or rather, include only audio files).

[SS64 on FOR](https://ss64.com/nt/for2.html) notes that you can have multiple patterns including wild cards separated by a standard delimiter.

So if you wanted to limit the selection to (for example) `.WAV` and `.MP3` files only, you could write:

```
FOR %%f IN (*.MP3,*.WAV) ...
```

---

*I recommend bookmarking SS64; it's a good succinct but detailed reference for Winbatch, PowerShell, and bash on both Linux and macOS.*

Comment: Good answer! I am not a Windows person so didn’t know about that comma formatting; pretty cool. In Bash one could do `*.{mp3,wav}` as an equivalent method.

Answer (score 4):

There is already a good answer here, but lets say that you want your script to include every single file but not your script, then the following alteration will explicitly skip your script:

You mentioned the script's name is `random.bat`.

```
@echo off
:: ##############################################################################
:: # Title:      Select a random filename in the current directory [ folder ].  #
:: # Created By: Paul Black at TenForums.com/members/paul-black.html            #
:: # Created:    October 2020.                                                  #
:: ##############################################################################
title Select A Random Filename.
mode con: cols=80 lines=5 & color 17
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set n=0
for %%f in (*.*) do (
  if not "%%f"=="random.bat" set /A n+=1
  if not "%%f"=="random.bat" set "file[!n!]=%%f"
)
set /A "RAND=(n*%Random%)/32768+1" & set /A "rand=(n*%Random%)/32768+1"
echo. & echo "!file[%RAND%]!"
echo. & echo ^>Press ANY key to EXIT . . . & pause >nul & exit
```

in the for loop where we loop through all files, we check if the current iteration is random.bat. If its not the case, we execute your code.

Comment: +1 Nice! Yet another way to skin a cat.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 thanks. Yeah. Your solution is probably what I'd normally go for, or even better, move the script out of the folder and start a cd /d first to change the path to it, but for the sake of education, it was not a hard thing to code in. :)

Comment: You might want to go even further and instead of checking for "random.bat" explicitly, check for `"%%f"=="%~nx0"`, which would allow you to call the file something other than `random.bat`. But even better would be your idea of moving it out of the folder and then doing a `CD /D ...` at the top...

Comment: @JeffZeitlin I can totally agree to check for `%~n0`. The only reason why I decided against that, is because the code as I posted it now will look logical to anyone, whereas this one looks like another language entirely. Where it does work, people tend to not trust code they don't understand that easily, Also because they don't understand it.

Comment: Whoa! That weird variable (`%~n0`) is well explained in [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8797999/117259). Cool learning about Windows Batch variables.

Comment: I'm learning all the time, thank you all so much!

Comment: @Giacomo1968 - There's a bit more on those 'weird variables' at [this page on SS64](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html).

Comment: it is superfluous to use `set /A "RAND=(n*%Random%)/32768+1"` twice,
 and in the same line is the first meaningless use. no one saw this? **`set /A "RAND=(n*%Random%)/32768+1" & set /A "rand=(n*%Random%)/32768+1"`**

Comment: @Io-oI I did not want to alter the script too much, so I only fixed the part that needed fixed and not completely rewrote the script.

Comment: I understand that this implies not correcting an explicit error that has less effect than the sum of the changes you applied. Your statement doesn't make sense: ***to alter the script too much*** 
What is the fear of changing what is necessary to improve/correct?

Comment: I personally frown upon changing the inner workings of a script, unless what it does is exactly the same. By using 2 times random, you get a different random number than doing it once. I have not tested the script fully to see if setting random enough times this way results in having the same random number twice in a row. I feel this was added for some weird usecase where the same number was returned twice.

Comment: In the same line it does not take on a different `!value!` than the `%first%` execution, it is the same `%number%` because using `%Random%`, so it does not expand to a different `%value%` at `!runtime!` execution in the `%second%` use, which makes it the `%first%` ineffective, because the `%second%` gives the same value.

Comment: Gosh this is really like going to school, I appreciate all the feedback. The initial response worked, but I'm tweaking as the discussion develops! :)

Answer (score 2):

```bash
:: ###############################################################################
:: #      Title:  Select a random filename in the current directory [ folder ].  #
:: # Created By:  Paul Black at TenForums.com/members/paul-black.html            #
:: #    Created:  October  2020.                                                 #
:: #     Edited:  December 2023.        https://superuser.com/a/1823108/969781   #
:: ###############################################################################

@echo off && setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set /a "_rand=0, _n=1" & mode.com con: cols=80 lines=05
title <nul & title Select A Random Filename. & color 17

for /f usebackq^delims^= %%G in =;(`
    where "%~dp0:*.*" ^| findstr /vei "\.cmd \.bat"
   `);= do set "_file_[!_n!]=%%~nxG" & set /a "_n+=1"
   
call set /a "_rand=(%%random:-=%% %%%% (!_n! - 1) + 1)"
>con: echo; & echo;"!_file_[%_rand%]!" & echo; & endlocal
timeout.exe /t -1 | set /p "`=>Press ANY key to EXIT . . ."
```

Or...

```bash
:: ###############################################################################
:: #      Title:  Select a random filename in the current directory [ folder ].  #
:: # Created By:  Paul Black at TenForums.com/members/paul-black.html            #
:: #    Created:  October  2020.                                                 #
:: #     Edited:  December 2023.        https://superuser.com/a/1823108/969781   #
:: ###############################################################################

@echo off && setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "_eXt=*.opus *.m4a *.mp3 *.flac *.aiff *.aac *.ogg *.wma"
set /a "_rand=0, _n=1" & mode con:cols=80lines=5 & cd /d "%~dp0"
title <nul & title Select A Random Audio Filename... && color 17

for /f usebackq^delims^= %%G in =;(` where "!cd!":!_eXt! 2^>nul
    `);= do set "_file_[!_n!]=%%~nxG" & set /a "_n+=1"

call set /a "_rand=(%%random:-=%% %%%% (!_n! - 1) + 1)"
>con: echo; & echo;"!_file_[%_rand%]!" & echo; & endlocal
timeout.exe /t -1 | set /p "`=>Press ANY key to EXIT..." & exit
```

---

> *How to get Paul Black's random file selector batch script not to select itself?*
>
> Replace the simple `for` with a `for /f` so that its output goes through:
>  `list your files | findstr /aVoid /Insensitive /End  ".cmd .bat"`
> Or explicitly specify audio extensions to filter files without
> selecting your **[.bat](/questions/tagged/.bat)** in the `for /f` loop

---

```bash
@echo off && setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

cd /d "%~dp0" & set /a "_skip=0, _nX=0"

title <nul & title Select A Random Filename.
mode.com con: cols=00080 lines=05 & color 17

for /f %%X in =;(' dir /a /b ^| find /v "%~x0" ^| find /c /v ""
    ');= do set /a "_nX=%%X-1, _skip=%random% %% %%X - 1"

if !_skip! equ 0 =;( 
        for /f delims^= %%f in =;(' dir /a:-d /b ^| find /v "%~x0"');= do set "_fn=%%~f" & echo. & goto %:^) 
    );= else =;( 
        for /f "skip=%_skip:-=% delims=" %%f in =;(' dir /a:-d /b ^| find /v "%~x0" ');= do set "_fn=%%~f" & echo. & goto %:^)
    );=
    
%:^)
echo/"!_fn!" & echo/ & timeout -1 | =;(
     set /p "`=> Press ANY key to EXIT . . ." & endlocal & exit
    );=
```

---

1. Count how many files you have in the folder by skipping the bat
2. Get random number between range `0 - [ total files - 1 ]`
3. Choose a random one in the range and jump straight to the file with a loop `For` using `skip={random range -1}`
4. There is no need to create a variable for **each file** name just to select one **after they are all defined**.

---

A suggestion to make a PowerShell call to select the file in a single loop:

```bash
@echo off & cd /d "%~dp0"
 
title <nul & title Select A Random Filename.
mode.com con: cols=00080 lines=05 & color 17

for /f usebackq^delims^= %%F in =;(`
    "PowerShell.exe Get-Random (gci ".\*" -ex *.cmd,*.bat).Name"
    `);= do echo/ & echo/"%%~nxF" & echo/ & timeout -1 |;= =;(
         set /p "`=> Press ANY key to EXIT . . ." );= & exit
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
for %%f in (*.*) do (
```

To limit it to `.mp3` files like this:

```
for %%f in (*.mp3) do (
```

Or just change that `.mp3` extension to better match your file naming conventions.